# Present the old small title of UINavigationBar in SwiftUI NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Until now the default `displayMode` for `UINavigationItem` was small title and it changed in SwiftUI to be large by default.

Is it possible to use the old small title style?

Answer (score 57):

It is possible by passing `displayMode: .inline` attribute to `navigationBarTitle()`

```
NavigationView {
  List {
    Text("Text")
  }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .inline)
}
```

Comment: Totally, but yet a bunch of things in SwiftUI are. There is a lot of room to improve.

Answer (score 29):

### iOS 14+

Starting from iOS 14 the `navigationBarTitle` modifier is **deprecated**.

Instead we should:

> "Use navigationTitle(*:) with navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(*:)"

```
List {
    Text("Text")
}
.navigationTitle("Title")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```